# How to get a nav bar to follow a page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website where at the top is a nav bar that will always be on the page even when scrolling down. Does anyone know how to do this? This is my current code

HTML

```
        <div id="navbar_wrapper">
            <h1 class="heading">heading</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#navbar_wrapper
{
background-image: url("../images/70%25_grey.png");
padding: 20px 20px;
color:white; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.heading
{
font-size:30pt;    
}

 nav ul li
 {
 margin-top:50px;    
 display:inline-block;    
 padding-right:18px;  
 }
```

Basically, i want that whole div to follow the page, and be shown at the top of the web browser window regardless of where you are on the page. I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use position:fixed for main Div. so it will fix on top always

```
#navbar_wrapper
{
background-image: url("../images/70%25_grey.png");
padding: 20px 20px;
color:white; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
position:fixed;
top:0
left:0; 
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in your CSS

```
ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Info About navigation bars created in css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)

Answer (score 0):

just use this css property in ***navbar_wrapper*** `position:fixed;` and this will work fine.
you can visit below link and see some example of *fixed property* of **css**.

visit : http://crackit9.blogspot.in/p/blog-page.html